# Building a recursion algorithm to check a 2d array of words

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am trying to build a Sudoku game with letters instead of numbers. There will be boxes like the following: [3 by 3 box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxiZB.png)

And the user will try to find the right permutation of letters such that all horizontal and all vertical letters form words. One game mode is that the user can use a subset of letters to fill out the boxes. For this game, I am using a special word list from a txt file, so I cannot use a standard dictionary library.
Here is an example of a correctly filled out puzzle:
[completed puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya7LJ.png)

For this version of Sudoku made for scrabble players, oxo is a valid word. Anyway, how would I build an algorithm to check that the horizontal and all vertical letters form words?

Comment: show us what you have done (share your codes)

Comment: @Ken Lee my Code is in Java, and spans multiple files. I was asking for a general algorithm, not for someone to write me the code.

Comment: For such a 3 X 3 box , there is only 6 words (horizontal + vertical). So just checking for 6 words will already be sufficient.

Comment: @KenLee Correct, however, this is easier said than done. If I have let us say 6 String containing the vertical and horizontal words, how do I check that all six "words" (3 letters entered by user) are actually found in the file? Would I create 6 different scanner objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks about checking whether 6 Strings are all valid words from a dictionary.

Pseudocode-ish Java for this:

```
  String[] boardWords = getWordsFromBoard(); // Should be a 6 element array.
  Set<String> dictionary = loadDictionary(); // Read all words from dictionary file into a Set.
  for (String word : boardWords) {
    if (!dictionary.contains(word)) return false;
  }
  return true;
```

Your comments in the question seem to indicate that you are wondering how to check 6 Strings against a dictionary and asking if you need to scan the dictionary 6 times. As you can see in the code above, you can load the contents of the dictionary to a collection once, and then just loop over the words and check if they occur in the collection.